# livestreamer does not recognize the url and options

Tags: bash

I'm doing a script on bash that fetch a json from an url, then parse it and finally try to open vlc and starts a live streming of that video through `livestreamer` application but the result is not the expected, it seems like `livestreamer` does not recognize a url and neither the parameters, the output on console its like I've executed the raw command application `livestreamer` without any param

here is the example code

```
# fetching from url
stream= # parsing json and get the hlsvariant url just like: hlsvariant://http://url

livestreamer "$stream" best -p vlc
```

the output is exactly the same as when you try `livestreamer` command in console whithout any parameter, just the application manual

Comment: The code you pasted certainly looks like you have an extra space after the `=` when assigning to `stream`.  If that's not the problem, post the actual code.

Comment: I've deleted the white sace like this `stream=curl -s "http://...." and the output is still the same

Comment: missing back ticks on stream assignment. problem solved!